# Iterating through 7 element lists using MIN, MAX and SUM

Tags: python-3.x, list

Need a way to iterate and find the following for each list:

- total in each list e.g., sum(p2720) and print them out highest to lowest.  For example the following dataset:

  p2720 = [240, 270, 103, 132, 117, 51, 10]

  p2721 = [204, 216, 104, 122, 110, 58, 6]

  p2723 = [582, 718, 293, 278, 227, 155, 6]

Would return highest to lowest and total. For example:

p2723 2259

p2720 923

p2721 820

...

Second, is there a way to loop through each element in each list and print:

```
max(p2720) is '240' which is the element '0'.
min(p2720) is '10' which is element '6'.
```

...

All the Best.
D

Comment: What have you tried, you've laid the question out well enough, maybe a key value dictionary with the pX as vey and SUM as value, then sorting them ?

Comment: What if there are two elements in a list with the same MAX or MIN value? Do you just want the first index in "...which is element 'x'"?

Comment: There are no min,max similar values.  Tested min, max and sum, Now I need to iterate over the 250 lists each containing 7 values to report the values for each list value 

    p2720 = [240, 270, 103, 132, 117, 51, 10]

    p2721 = [204, 216, 104, 122, 110, 58, 6]

For each variable need to print the following:

print 

p2720[0] contains 240
p2720[1] contains 270
p2729[2] contains 103

and so on - perhaps a loop would be best to read and print each list.  

Best,

Comment: Here is my progress - is there an easier way?

Code to iterate over *multiple* lists: 

     p1234 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]   
    p4567 = [2, 4, 9, 12, 0]  

   
# Using for loop 
    for i in p1234: 
        print(i) 
// for each list trying to print

0 is 1

1 is 3

2 is 5

3 is 7

4 is 9



print (the sum for p1234 is sum(p1234))

print (Max value:  max(p1234)  member p1234[4])

print (Min value:  min(p1234)  member p1234[0])

Comment: Here is an example of a working single set using the itertools - but I would like to accomodate around 250 lists hence the thought to use looping. 
import itertools

# districts
p2027 = [1, 2, 3]
p2029 = [4, 9, 10]
p2030 = [4, 6, 8]

totala = 0
totalb = 0
totalc = 0
for (a, b, c) in (p2027, p2029, p2030) :

    totala += a
    totalb += b
    totalc += c

    print(" Dave got: ", a)
    print(" George got ", b)
    print (" Sally got ", c)
    print ()

print ("Total for p2027 ", totala)

print ("Total for p2029 ", totalb)

print ("Total for p2030 ", totalc)

Comment: Actually, used python's import csv feature to create Excel ready file, then read it and checked it, and was able to hand it to Excel with minimal code:

import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('DATA.csv')
print(df)

Thanks while I sorted ;) it out.